# c++ count amount of numbers in char array?

Tags: c++, char

I have a char array that has number 0-8 in it in char form

```
Board[0] = '0';
Board[1] = '1';
Board[2] = '2';
Board[3] = '3';
Board[4] = '4';
Board[5] = '5';
Board[6] = '6';
Board[7] = '7';
Board[8] = '8';
```

and some of them are changed to either an 'x' or an 'o' based on user input however I need to figure out a way so that I can tell the total number of them that aren't an 'x' or an 'o'.

What I mean is if say 4 of the 9 are either an 'x' or an 'o' I need to be able to get the fact that there are 5 left. I was attempting to use `for each(char c in Board)` and I got far enough to where I got it to list the chars that aren't an 'x' or an 'o' but I can't figure out how to get it to send how many are left to an int value. This is as far as I got.

```
    for each(char c in Board)
    {
        if (c != 'x' && c != 'o')
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: `for each(... in ...)` is not C++.

Comment: considering I wrote in in c++ and it works. yes it is

Comment: It is not *standard* C++ for sure.

Comment: I am using vs compiler so that may be why

Comment: @IanLundberg: Nope. Perhaps C++-CLI, and if so it should be tagged as such.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 iostream library is only library I am using and it worked.

Comment: You're evidently writing a tic-tac-toe game for school. I've assigned homework like that before. Rather than count how many moves have been made by looking at the board, I'd instead recommend counting each move as it happens. Increment a counter on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Even if your compiler accepts that syntax, I wouldn't recommend submitting it. Your instructor expects you to use the syntax you've been taught this semester. Consult your textbook and class notes for the syntax of `for` loops. If you turn in this non-standard code, and your instructor isn't using the same compiler, then you'll probably get marked down because your instructor will be unable to test it.

Comment: @RobKennedy haha already made one of those and didn't even think of using it in this situation thanks and you have a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a counter that counts the number of these characters (by incrementing it):

```
int n = 0;
for (char c : Board)
{
    if (c != 'x' && c != 'o')
    {
        n++; // increment n by 1
    }
}

std::cout << n << '\n'; // use the result
```

Comment: Another idea is to start with a variable counting the number of free spaces and decrement for every move.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
auto n = std::count_if(Board, Board+9, std::isdigit);
```

Comment: It is not `is_digit`, it is `isdigit`.

Comment: @Astor there seem to be no '9' ;) corrected the misspelling, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
#include <cctype>    // for std::isdigit
#include <algorithm> // for std::count_if

int num = std::count_if(Board, Board+9, std::isdigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't just want *any* digit, and only those between 0 and 8 you could do this:

```
int count = 0;

for each(char c in Board)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '8')
    {
        count++;
    }
}

cout << count << " are digits between 0 and 8 (inclusive)" << endl;
```